# MOTD - show memory usage

Tags: bash, scripts, landscape

I'm a n00b when it comes to bash scripting, so I was hoping someone could help me out.

I have a server running 11.04, and my message of the day includes how much memory is currently used:

```
System information as of Tue Sep 24 10:58:28 MDT 2013

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           90
  Usage of /:   16.6% of 19.68GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 49%                IP address for eth0: XX.XX.XX.XX
  Swap usage:   12%                IP address for eth1: XX.XX.XX.XX
```

I spun up another server running 13.04, and that message isn't there. So it looked into how to add it, and found on my 11.04 server under `/etc/update-motd.d` there is a link to a script at `/usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cores=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null)
[ "$cores" -eq "0" ] && cores=1
threshold="${cores:-1}.0"
if [ $(echo "`cut -f1 -d ' ' /proc/loadavg` < $threshold" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo
    echo -n "  System information as of "
    /bin/date
    echo
    /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
else
    echo
    echo " System information disabled due to load higher than $threshold"
fi
```

I added this script to my 13.04 server, but the script must be running into an error somewhere because it shows the "else" message, "System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0". Both servers have the same specs, other than the version of Ubuntu they're running. How can I edit this script on my 13.04 system to get it to show current memory usage?

**UPDATE:**

It looks like 13.04 doesn't have landscape. I ran `dpkg -l | grep landscape` and no results. 11.04 has it running. So I guess the question is, how can I show memory usage without landscape?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why your `dpkg` command didn't return the [`landscape-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/landscape-common) package because it [**does exist**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/landscape-common) in Raring and [owns the `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=landscape-sysinfo&mode=exactfilename&suite=raring&arch=any).

Install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-common
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your memory usage in a landscape like way:

```
free -k | {
    read ; read TITLE TOTAL USED REST
    echo "Memory usage: $(( 100 * $USED / $TOTAL ))%"

    #you also want swap displayed ?  No problem

    read ; read TITLE TOTAL USED REST
    echo "Swap usage:   $(( 100 * $USED / $TOTAL ))%"

}
```